# How to set the number of items per page in a CGridView?

Tags: php, pagination, yii

I have a project in Yii where there is a `CGridView` that by default shows 10 records per page. How can I set this to 100 records?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Find in your view the place where the `CGridView` widget is being rendered, and configure the `pagination` property of the data provider:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider' => array(
         /* other options for the data provider... */
        'pagination' => array('pageSize' => 100),
    ),
    /* other options for the grid view... */
));
```

Comment: @MickSegvezent: Looks like the data provider overrides it, then. See the update.

Comment: @CarlosAlbertoMartínezGadea: This is an example of what to do, not a magic spell you put in your code that makes it work no matter what. There are millions of reasons why you might still run into a problem.

Comment: @Jon thanks for getting back to me, actually I wanted to coment again because the reason it didn't work for me is that I was using at that point a CArrayDataProvider, which doesn't work directly with the 'pagination' param. Although it works like a charm with the regular CActiveDataProvider. I've deleted my last comment so I don't mess anybody with that simple and unconcrete comment ;)

Answer (score 11):

You can configure in Search function of the Model like below:

```
public function search()
{
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id,true);
    $criteria->compare('start_year',$this->start_year,true);
    $criteria->compare('end_year',$this->end_year,true);
    $criteria->compare('ref_lang_id',$this->ref_lang_id);
    $criteria->compare('submitted_at',$this->submitted_at,true);
    $criteria->compare('ref_submitted_user_id',$this->ref_submitted_user_id,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'pagination' => array(
            'pageSize' => 30,
        ),
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the items per page with a dropdown.

[image]

To create a section like this. Follow the steps below.

Define custom template for the section "Displaying 1-10 of 128" section on the screenshot.

Add this piece of code with your Gridview properties array.

```
'summaryText' => 'Displaying {start}-{end} of {count} result(s). ' .
    CHtml::dropDownList('pageSize', $pageSize, Yii::app()->params['pageSizeOptions'], array('class' => 'change-pageSize')) .' rows per page',
```

Add this line on the top of view

```
$pageSize = Yii::app()->user->getState('pageSize', Yii::app()->params['defaultPageSize']);
```

Add Change event in the same view.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
$('body').on('change','.change-pageSize', function () {
    $.fn.yiiGridView.update('my-grid', {data: {pageSize: $(this).val()}
    })
});
});
```

Add This line in Model search function, to set the selected rows count in Active data provider.

```
$pageSize = Yii::app()->user->getState('pageSize', Yii::app()->params['defaultPageSize']);
```

Then in the controller receive the page size parameter sent from view through ajax. Use the following line of code in controller.

```
if (isset($_GET['pageSize'])) {
                Yii::app()->user->setState('pageSize', (int) $_GET['pageSize']);
            }
```

Add This configuration in Params.php

```
'defaultPageSize' => 20,
'pageSizeOptions' => array(-1 =>'All' , 10 => 10, 20 => 20, 50 => 50, 100 => 100, 500 => 500),
```

**This Worked for me!**